# Do While loop with Yes = start again No = exit Program

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I have to add a do-while loop to my project so after the program iterates it says: "You want a run this program again? (Yes or No)"

If user inputs are Yes or YEs or YES or yEs or yES or yeS
It runs a program again.
If it's no, program should automatically exit.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatePay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


        String Name = " ";
        int hours;
        double payRate;
        char F;
        char P;
        char T;

        String input = " ";
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);

        double grossPay;

        int attempt = 0;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        Name = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many hours did you work? ");
        hours = reader.nextInt();
        while (hours < 0 || hours > 280) 
        {
            System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
            hours = reader.nextInt();
            attempt++;
            if(attempt >= 2) {
                System.out.println("You are Fired!");
                    return ;
            }       
        }
        System.out.print("What is your pay rate? ");
        payRate = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What type of employee are you? ");
        F = reader.next().charAt(0);
        grossPay = hours * payRate;
        DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        switch (F)
        {
            case 'F' :
            case 'f' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a full-time employee");
                if (hours < 0)  
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            case 'P' :
            case'p' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a part- time employee");
                if (hours < 0)  
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            case 'T' :
            case 't' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a temporary employee");
                if (hours < 0)  
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" unknown employee type");

                if (hours < 0)  
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }
            } 
            System.out.println("Do you want to run this program again? (Yes or No)");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest yo to wrap your logic in another method, so you can call it later:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatePay {

    private static void doStuff() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Name = " ";
        int hours;
        double payRate;
        char F;
        char P;
        char T;

        String input = " ";
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);

        double grossPay;
        int attempt = 0;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        Name = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many hours did you work? ");
        hours = reader.nextInt();
        while (hours < 0 || hours > 280)
        {
            System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
            hours = reader.nextInt();
            attempt++;
            if(attempt >= 2) {
                System.out.println("You are Fired!");
                return ; }

        }
        System.out.print("What is your pay rate? ");
        payRate = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What type of employee are you? ");
        F = reader.next().charAt(0);


        grossPay = hours * payRate;
        DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");




        switch (F)
        {
            case 'F' :
            case 'f' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a full-time employee");
                if (hours < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            case 'P' :
            case'p' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a part- time employee");
                if (hours < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            case 'T' :
            case 't' :
                System.out.println("Hi " + Name + ", you made $" + decFor.format(grossPay) + " this week"+" as a temporary employee");
                if (hours < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" unknown employee type");



                if (hours < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (hours > 280)
                {
                    System.out.print(" That's not possible ");
                }
                else if (grossPay >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(" You must be a Java programmer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" this week");
                }


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            //Call your bussines logic.
            doStuff();

            System.out.println("Do you want to run this program again? (Yes or No)");
        }
        while(reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("yes"));
    } }
```

Note that the function is `static`. This is because you can not call a non-static method from a `static` context (main is static).

Comment: so What should I do if I want to add another "yes" like "Yes" "YEs" "yES" "yEs" "yeS" ?

Comment: It is already got handled by `toLowerCase()`, but probably should used `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead...

Comment: BTW the "yes"/"no" logic is broken, as anything other than "yes" treated as "no"....

Comment: Sure. In that case the program should ask for every String not equals to "no", and therefore anything else "no" will repeat the cycle:         while(!reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("no"));

Comment: Nope, you need 2 loops: first is like what you have now, the inner that checks for "yes"/"no"...

Comment: Also do not use multiple `Scanner` on the same input, as it might get closed, thus closing `System.in` in this case...